# Why is my SVG use element showing a different d to the path it references? (screenshot attached)

Tags: javascript, svg, position, shadow-dom

[image: screenshot of issue]

I'm trying to `use` a `path` from `defs`. A path appears visually so the reference is right but has a rather different `d` value (apparent from the shadow DOM) to the original path.

It appears to be some kind of scaling/positioning issue but I haven't added any transforms to either the original path or the used one.

Screenshot shows the DOM + shadow DOM from inspect element in chrome.

If it helps, both elements were created with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the problem was having two SVG paths on the page with the same ID.